# getting truncated incorrect double value: '1GA22AD061'

Tags: python, sql

my python function is as follows

```
def add_data(self):
        if self.var_dep.get() == "Select Department" or self.var_StudentID.get() == "" or self.var_Student_Name.get() == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields are required", parent=self.root)
        else:
            try:
                conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Tejas@23", database="database_face_")
                my_cursor = conn.cursor()
                my_cursor.execute("insert into student values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (
                    self.var_dep.get(),
                    self.var_Course.get(),
                    self.var_Year.get(),
                    self.var_Semester.get(),
                    self.var_StudentID.get(),
                    self.var_Student_Name.get(),
                    self.var_Gender.get(),
                    self.var_email.get(),
                    self.var_Phone_no.get(),
                    self.var_DOB.get(),
                    self.var_Lecturer.get(),
                    self.var_Address.get(),
                    self.var_Class_div.get(),
                    self.var_Mentor.get(),
                    self.var_radio1.get()
                ))
                conn.commit()
                self.fetch_data()
                conn.close()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Student details have been added successfully", parent=self.root)
            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Database Error: {err}", parent=self.root)
```

the interface and its error:
[image]

i want the student id to be varchar only and i declared it as varchar but still the problem persists

i tried some solutions provided by chatgpt and other websites but the problem is still there

Comment: Can you share the table structure (create table statement) and some sample data that reproduces the problem  please?

Comment: Are you sure that your database column order corresponds to the order of parameters in your insert?